# Idempotant guarantee in Confluent Rest Proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest, confluent-rest-proxy

Currently, I am using Confluent Rest Proxy 5.5.1 for collecting data in production. Duplicated events can come. I found the solution for de-duplication using Kafka Stream API. Is it possible to get an idempotent producer guarantee in Rest Proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the REST Proxy's producer client with the `producer.` prefix

```
producer.enable.idempotence=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Idempotent producers are not supported in Kafka REST. Ignoring 'enable.idempotence'. (io.confluent.kafkarest.KafkaRestConfig:880)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).